# Перенос контента с DLE на Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, изображения, wordpress-плагины, миграция

Всем привет. Сделал миграцию базы с DLE на Wordpress. 160к+ (да-да, 160к+) постов перенеслось с категориями, датами. Изображения в постах вставлены ссылками, отображаются. Как реализовать, чтобы изображения загрузились в библиотеку Wordpress и чтобы установилось главное изображение записи?
Делал все по мануалу https://alexell.ru/blog/php-wordpress/perenos-sajta-s-dle-na-wordpress.html

Comment: Выкинь базу от ВП и сделай заново через импорт контента. А тот хлам, что по ссылке - забудь. Читай [правильные мануалы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562) (тут тебе нужно только объяснение почему ты сотворил фигню и гемморой для будущей жизни сайта. А перенос контента из других движков - отдельная тема)